# JS keeps overwriting my previous "code"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a browser based OS. To figure a few things out, I wrote the following code. When I run it, the code at the beginning keeps getting left out.

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>
   OS ... Loading
  </TITLE>
  <LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="loader.css" />
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <SCRIPT>
 setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\"Booting\")
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\" .\")
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\".\")
}, 3000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\".\")
}, 4000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\" OK\")
}, 6000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\"<BR>Volume.php\")
}, 8000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\" .\")
}, 9000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\".\")
}, 10000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\".\")
}, 11000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\" OK\")
}, 13000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\"<BR>IE.php\")
}, 15000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\" .\")
}, 16000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\".\")
}, 17000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\".\")
}, 18000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.write(\" OK\")
}, 20000);
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Comment: `document.write` is difficult to use at best. It wipes the body of the html and replaces it with the string in the write. So in your case, since you have your script in the body tag, the script will get replaced as soon as the script starts to run.

Comment: The reason people say not to use document.write is due to security, similar to how people say don't use eval. But also it's pretty much "considered" as depreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @pero's answer

> The **Element.innerHTML** property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Use `Element.innerHTML +=` to append preformatted html to the element.
Use `Element.innerHTML =` to replace the preformatted html of the element.

```
document.body.innerHTML += 'some text'
```

> The **Node.textContent** property represents the text content of a node and its descendants.
>   ...
>
> #### Differences from innerHTML
>
> innerHTML returns the HTML as its name indicates. Quite often, in order to retrieve or write text within an element, people use innerHTML. textContent should be used instead. Because the text is not parsed as HTML, it's likely to have better performance. Moreover, this avoids an XSS attack vector.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Use `Element.textContent +=` to append text to the element.
Use `Element.textContent =` to replace the text of the element.

```
document.body.textContent += 'some text'
```

#### More specific

If you want to append/replace the text/html for a certain element you need to select that element, then use the above methods on that element

For example,

Let's say you have a `div`,

```
<div class="screen"></div>
```

that you would like to append `some text` to. Here we select the first div with the class `screen` (although you should use a unique id instead of a class) and append `some text` to it.

```
document.querySelector('.screen').textContent += 'some text'
```

If you're going to use a unique id you would select it like so

```
document.getElementById('screen');
```

Now if you're going to be doing this a whole bunch of times, you should cache the selector so you're not querying the dom every time.

```
var screen = document.querySelector('.screen');
screen.textContent += 'some ';
screen.textContent += 'text ';
screen.textContent += 'some more text';
```

#### A note about innerHTML/textContent vs DOM Manipulation

The above methods are great for quickly appending text or html to an element, no doubt about it, and it performs more quickly than DOM Manipulation.

> The most obvious conclusion of these tests is that innerHTML is faster than "real" W3C DOM methods in all browsers. The W3C DOM table methods are slow to very slow, especially in Explorer.
>
> More than once people said that creating elements only once and then cloning them when necessary leads to a dramatic performance improvement. These tests don't show anything of that kind. Although in most browsers cloning is minimally faster than creating, the difference between the two methods is small.
>   http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html

**But** DOM Manipulation has a lot of wonderful features that cannot be easily accomplished by the methods detailed in my answer. For complex operations I would definitely recommend [DOM Manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples).

Comment: one last question what about its interaction with the setTimeout do i use () or is += still the right way to go

Comment: just one last part (I am new to JS and not sure where to look to find answers other than here) I want to place the js script in my `<DIV CLASS="screen">` but not sure how to mke sure that happens with the code you gave me?

Comment: yes that is exactly my intention and I'm not sure how to specify which div to attach it to

Answer (score 4):

The MDN documentation for [`Document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) is pretty clear about this:

> Note: as **document.write** writes to the document **stream**, calling
>   document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls
>   **document.open** which will clear the document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open#Notes

**Use [DOM manipulation](http://callmenick.com/post/basics-javascript-dom-manipulation) instead**

e.g. at it's most basic:

```js
var h = document.createElement("h1");
var t = document.createTextNode("Unicorns!");
h.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(h);
```

Comment: I know that my problem is in the document.write() what I can't figure out is what to replace it with.